# Как вытащить наименование компании через регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.
Как вытащить наименование компании через регулярное выражение.
Заранее благодарен!

Варианты (иногда через пробел и без пробела):
ООО 'РОГА'
ООО "РОГА"
ООО «РОГА»

```
import re
result = re.findall('(?i)(ооо|ип|зао)', 'привет ООО "РОГА" привет')
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'((ооо|ип|зао)\s+[\'"«].*?[\'"»])', 'привет ООО "РОГА" привет', re.I)`

Comment: @ΝNL993 спасибо большое! еще бы с низу написали в ответе, чтобы я отметил как правильный ответ

Comment: Не за что! Оформил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
re.findall('((ооо|ип|зао)\s+[\'"«].*?[\'"»])', 'привет ООО "РОГА" привет', re.I)
```

### Объяснение

Сразу упомяну что я использовать флаг `re.I` (то же самое что и`re.IGNORECASE`), который делает нас независимым от кейса букв в строке, то-есть на важно будут буквы заглавные или нет. Теперь начнём с регулярного выражения. В начале мы матчим группу строк, если у нас совпадение, продолжаем. Дальше мы матчим пробел, должен быть как минимум 1 пробел, можно писать больше, это нам обеспечивает символ `+`, после `\s` (whitespace). Далее, в квадратных скобках мы вписываем диапазон символов которые могут совпасть, само название может быть любым, главное, чтобы слева и справа были бы кавычки.

Answer (score 2):

1. Аббревиатуры ОПФ оформляем как незахватываемую группу `(?:...)`
2. Пробелы/кавычки любых типов перед между ОПФ и названием забираем как последовательность 1+ не-словесных (non-word) символов `\W+`. Видов кавычек довольно много, чтобы их все не перечислять, можно применить такой подход.
3. Забираем последовательность 1+ словесных или пробельных символов
4. В конце забираем 1 любой замыкающий символ

```
texts = """ООО 'РОГА'
ООО "РОГА"
пао «РОГА»
пао(РОГА)
пирога
ООО'РОГА и копыта'
"РОГА"
ООО «РОГА»
ип `иванов иван иванович` 
привет ООО "РОГА" привет"""

print(*re.findall(r'(?:ооо|ип|зао|ao|пао)\W+[\w\s]+.', texts, re.IGNORECASE), sep='\n')
```

```
ООО 'РОГА'
ООО "РОГА"
пао «РОГА»
пао(РОГА)
ООО'РОГА и копыта'
ООО «РОГА»
ип `иванов иван иванович`
ООО "РОГА"
```